# Is there a Angular 2 lifehook that initializes when the component is being displayed

Tags: angular, rxjs

Ok this is going to be simply the biggest overkill you have ever seen, but please take into consideration that this is just my pet project for resume.

What i was trying to do is to display breadcrumbs of user location in my breadcrumbs component component instead of repeating the toolbar code each time, so i needed some way to comunicate user location from different components back to breadcrumbs component. So i created the BreadcrumbService:

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Breadcrumb} from "./breadcrumb";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";
@Injectable()
export class BreadcrumbService {
  private breadcrumbs:Subject<Breadcrumb[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.breadcrumbs = new Subject();
  }

  getBreadcrumbs():Subject<Breadcrumb[]>{
    return this.breadcrumbs;
  }

  setBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs:Breadcrumb[]){
    this.breadcrumbs.next(breadcrumbs)
  }

}
```

I use RxJs Subject to broadcast breadcrumbs to the subscriber.
And because i need it too be a singleton I also created a BreadcrumbModule

```js
import {BreadcrumbService} from "./breadcrumb.service";
import {BreadcrumbComponent} from "./breadcrumb.component";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {MaterialModule} from "@angular/material";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "../app-routing.module";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [BreadcrumbComponent],
  providers: [BreadcrumbService],
  exports: [BreadcrumbComponent]
})
export class BreadcrumbModule {

}
```

That declared the breadcrumb component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-breadcrumbs',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'breadcrumb.template.html'
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {

  private breadcrumbs:Breadcrumb[];
  private breadcrumbsSubject:Subject<Breadcrumb[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breadcrumbsSubject.subscribe(
      (breadcrumbs)=> {
        this.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;
      });

    let breadcrumbs:Breadcrumb[] = [new Breadcrumb("HOME", ["/"])];
    this.breadcrumbService.setBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs);
  }

  constructor(private breadcrumbService:BreadcrumbService) {
    this.breadcrumbsSubject = this.breadcrumbService.getBreadcrumbs();
  }

}
```

And injected it into my other components

```js
export class FolderComponent implements OnInit {
  private breadcrumbs:Breadcrumb[];
  constructor(*other services*, private breadcrumbService:BreadcrumbService) {
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    getBreadcrumbs();
  }
  getBreadcrumbs():void {
    //some code
    this.breadcrumbService.setBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs);
  }
```

So they could change the breadcrumbs to the one thy need, the problem is that i have naively thought that onInit() lifehook will be called each time the component is displayed but it seems like it is being called only once during it construction.

And yes this is ridiculous but i want to know in case if in the future i would need something like this: is there a way to call a function inside a component each time it being displayed, and by the way what is the best way to deal with those goddemn breadcrumbs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in Root app Component and listening route.

```js
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Route, private breadcrumbService:BreadcrumbService) {
        router.events.subscribe((val) => {
            // see also 
            this.breadcrumbService.setBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs);
        });
    }
    title = "app works!";
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, i have solved this more traditional way: by passing data into child directive as @Input and multiplying instances of breadcrumb directive across different routes, but i think this may be also useful someday.